# How to make https service deployed locally to receive data from internet service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, service, salesforce

I have service, which should serve to events triggered in third party service (Salesforce). But I need to test and debug my service, so I need to run it locally and make it visible to the third party service, so it can send me data on trigger.

In simple word I need to debug https service without deploying it. I need free solution so for example ngrok is unfortunately out of the question.

I will be grateful for any tips.

EDIT: it is ASP.NET service

Comment: What kind of service it is? ASP.NET, WCF or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running **[nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)** locally. **Nginx** is a **free** proxy/load balancer, which will pass incoming HTTP requests to your app host. Remember to add **incoming firewall rule** in order to make **nginx** visible to 3rd party services (i.e. Salesfoce).

Answer (score 0):

I use https://ngrok.com/ for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, I would like to, but in free version it supports only http

Comment: Ah. They must have changed that recently because https used to be free.